# optimize Mysql: get latest status of the sale

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, exists

In the following query, I show the latest status of the sale (by stage, in this case the number 3). The query is based on a subquery in the status history of the sale:

```
SELECT v.id_sale, 
IFNULL((
    SELECT (CASE WHEN IFNULL( vec.description, '' ) = ''
                    THEN ve.name
                    ELSE vec.description
                    END)
    FROM t_record veh
    INNER JOIN t_state_campaign vec ON vec.id_state_campaign = veh.id_state_campaign
    INNER JOIN t_state ve ON ve.id_state = vec.id_state
    WHERE veh.id_sale = v.id_sale
    AND vec.id_stage = 3
    ORDER BY veh.id_record DESC
    LIMIT 1
), 'x') sale_state_3
FROM t_sale v
INNER JOIN t_quarters sd ON v.id_quarters = sd.id_quarters
WHERE 1 =1
AND v.flag =1
AND v.id_quarters =4
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT '1'
    FROM t_record
    WHERE id_sale = v.id_sale
    LIMIT 1
)
```

the query delay **0.0057seg** and show **1011 records**.

Because I have to filter the sales by the name of the state as it would have to repeat the subquery in a where clause, I have decided to change the same query using joins. In this case, I'm using the MAX function to obtain the latest status:

```
SELECT
v.id_sale,
IFNULL(veh3.State3,'x') AS sale_state_3
FROM t_sale v
INNER JOIN t_quarters sd ON v.id_quarters = sd.id_quarters
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT veh.id_sale, 
    (CASE WHEN IFNULL(vec.description,'') = '' 
        THEN ve.name
        ELSE vec.description END) AS State3
    FROM t_record veh
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id_sale, MAX(id_record) AS max_rating
                FROM(
                    SELECT veh.id_sale, id_record
                    FROM t_record veh
                    INNER JOIN t_state_campaign vec ON vec.id_state_campaign = veh.id_state_campaign AND vec.id_stage = 3
                ) m
            GROUP BY id_sale    
    ) x ON x.max_rating = veh.id_record
    INNER JOIN t_state_campaign vec ON vec.id_state_campaign = veh.id_state_campaign
    INNER JOIN t_state ve ON ve.id_state = vec.id_state
) veh3 ON veh3.id_sale = v.id_sale
WHERE v.flag = 1
AND v.id_quarters = 4
```

This query shows the same results (1011). But the problem is it takes **0.0753 sec**

Reviewing the possibilities I have found the factor that makes the difference in the speed of the query:

```
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT '1'
    FROM t_record
    WHERE id_sale = v.id_sale
    LIMIT 1
)
```

If I remove this clause, both queries the same time delay...  Why it works better? Is there any way to use this clause in the joins? I hope your help.

**EDIT**

I will show the results of EXPLAIN for each query respectively:

**q1:**
[image]

**q2:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, so that little statement basically determines if there is a match between t_record.id_sale and t_sale.id_sale.

Why is this making your query run faster? Because Where statements applied prior to subSelects in the select statement, so if there is no record to go with the sale, then it doesn't bother processing the subSelect. Which is netting you some time. So that's why it works better.

Is it going to work in your join syntax? I don't really know without having your tables to test against but you can always just apply it to the end and find out. Add the keyword EXPLAIN to the beginning of your query and you will get a plan of execution which will help you optimize things. Probably the best way to get better results in your join syntax is to add some indexes to your tables.

But I ask you, is this even necessary? You have a query returning in <8 hundredths of a second. Unless this query is getting ran thousands of times an hour, this is not really taxing your DB at all and your time is probably better spent making improvements elsewhere in your application.

Comment: thanks for your response. For me it is important time for the simple reason that the query I am showing is only a state of the sale. he real query shows different states per stage (Each a subquery / join) and if we are adding the times, there comes a time when the query may take 1.5 seconds. against 0.3xxx sec. So it would be interesting to know if there is any way to optimize the joins. The index tables are for example in Table t_record: i_id_record, i_id_state_campaign, i_id_sale...